# Embed a webpage into my website

Tags: url, iframe, web, hide, embed

I want to embed a website into my webpage. I tried using Iframe but some website do not allow that and will not display. Is there any other way?

Comment: If this website restricts iframe usage it is very likely it not meant to be embedded in any way and you should respect that. Consult their ToS rather than use any programming hacks.

Comment: I will use it for a hide url service. So someone can send you a link like mywebsite.com/ioehrq and when you open it it actually has another website on it but the url bar still reads mywebsite.com/ioehrq. And it will be the users choice what website they want to embed.